# bashでシングルクォートを含む文字列を正規表現マッチさせる

Tags: bash

VimのNeoBundleプラグインにプラグインを追加するスクリプトを書いています。

そのため、以下のような文字列を正規表現マッチで検出したいと考えています。

`NeoBundle 'hoge/fuga.vim'`

この場合、閉じシングルクォートを除けば以下のような条件式でマッチできるのですが、閉じシングルクォートを含む条件式がわかりません。

```
$ query="NeoBundle 'hoge/fuga.vim'"
$ echo "$query" | grep -oE $'NeoBundle \'[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+/[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+'
NeoBundle 'hoge/fuga.vim
```

予めシングルクォートを置換するなどの対策は可能だと思いますが、対象の文字列を変更せずに正規表現マッチできないでしょうか。

Comment: こうですか？ `echo "$query" | grep -oE $'NeoBundle \'[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+/[.0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\''`
　　　# `.` が抜けている様な気がしますが…

Comment: 本来の質問とは関係ありませんが、正規表現として `[]` 内の `-` をエスケープしたければ、\ を bash の文字列としてエスケープしなくてはならないので `$'NeoBundle \'[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+/[.0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+\''` とする方が分かりやすいでしょう。

逆にできるだけ簡潔に書きたいのなら、`[]` 内末尾の `-` にはエスケープ不要なので `$'NeoBundle \'[0-9a-zA-Z-]+/[.0-9a-zA-Z-]+\''` でいいのではないでしょうか。

ダブルクォート " で囲んだほうが見やすくなるのは、他の回答にあるとおりです。

Comment: 凡ミスでした……。お恥ずかしい。
`-`を末尾に書けばエスケープ不要とは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: grep の POSIX 正規表現 (BRE/ERE) では、広く使われている Perl 系の正規表現と違って、bracket expression `[～]` の中でエスケープは使えません。`grep '[\-]'` は「'-' または '\'」に一致してしまいます。なので「エスケープ不要」ではなく、むしろ「エスケープは誤り」です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@argusさんが指摘したとおり、マッチしない直接の原因は正規表現内にドット`.`と末尾のシングルクォート`'`が抜けていることだと思います。

表題のように正規表現文字列にシングルクオートを含めたいならば、文字列をダブルクォートで囲む方法が直感的に分かりやすいです。

```
$ grep -oE "NeoBundle '[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+/[.0-9a-zA-Z\-]+'"
```

文字列をシングルクォートで囲んでいる場合は、ちょっとトリッキーになります。

```
$ grep -oE 'NeoBundle '\''[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+/[.0-9a-zA-Z\-]+'\'''
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。実際にはこれをさらにエイリアスしたりしているので、ダブルクォートではなく`$''`を用いていました。